# Track /etc/nixos/result in VCS?

Tags: nixos, version-control, nix

While one can rollback NixOS build generations easily, this won't give back the corresponding NixOS configuration in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`. Thus, it seems to be common to track `/etc/nixos/` in a version control system (VCS) e.g. in Git.

When doing so, should the `/etc/nixos/result` symlink also be tracked? Why?/Why not?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any significant advantage in doing it, but maybe my use cases have been too simple in this respect.

I prefer to watch `ls -l /nix/var/nix/profiles/` and/or `ls -l /nix/var/nix/profiles/system-profiles`, based on whether you name your system profile(s), and I typically delete by hand the symlinks that I want garbage-collected.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of your `configuration.nix` in it's corresponding generation. You just need to create a reference to it (within itself) so that it becomes part of the closure. Here's an example:

#### configuration.nix

```
{ config, lib, pkgs, ... }:
{
  # yada, yada

  environment.etc."configuration.nix".source = /etc/nixos/configuration.nix;
};
```

The `environment.etc` [option](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#etc) allows you to declarative-ly create files in `/etc`. Nix will detect `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` as a `path` type (paths are first-class types in Nix) and thus copy it's contents into the Nix store. The result is a symbolic link `/etc/configuration.nix` pointing (indirectly) to `/nix/store/blah-blah-configuration.nix`, which means each generation will have a `/etc/configuration.nix` symbolic link pointing to it's corresponding configuration. You can then do something similar with additional files, such as `hardware-configuration.nix`.

### The catch

Although the above will store your configuration, it will not make it usable by `nix-env`, `nix-shell`, `nixos-rebuild`, etc, because those commands use `$NIX_PATH` to locate configs. While you *may* be able to address this (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47961494/propagate-nixpkgs-checkout-to-nixops-machines/48052945#48052945)) I don't recommend it because when you run `nixos-rebuild` it will use the wrong config file (`/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` rather than the copy in the Nix store, which is read-only anyway). Things would get wonky real quick.

And of course the Nix store is *world-readable*.